# Persistent issues with MAUI trying to build iOS Archive

Tags: xcode, maui

I don't know if it is just me, but I never, ever seem to have an easy time with MAUI and having anything to do with iOS/the Mac connection. Never deploys to the simulator, can't run it on a device whether its plugged into the Mac host or windows.

I could live with all of that if I could actually publish the damn thing.

Running Visual Studio 2022 17.8.3 (Latest) and the latest build of mac OS (Sonoma) and the latest version of XCode (

> Cannot create an IOS archive . process cannot be executed on XMA server. /usr/bin/sodesign exited with code 1.
> Code object is not signed at all  System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll

It was working 2 days ago. Now it stopped. I've tried Cleaning the solution, restarting both Windows machine and the Mac. The apple accounts are valid in both XCode and VS.

How can I get this working, or is there a better way to publish a MAUI app for iOS?

I'd even settle for doing it in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found using the UI to br extremely poor. Just not enough information provided anywhere I could see that would usefully help me debug what was going on.

So I resorted to the command line thanks to this article.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0

The output from running that provided me all the information needed so i could fix things up and eventually get deploying.

Comment: 1. Yes, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0 on how to publish an iOS app using the command line.  2. Also, you can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.